# TypeScript push not available on interface array

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define an interface that is an array as explained here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types and then push items to it. The problem is that TypeScript says that push doesn't exists.

I have tried the following example in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20StringArray%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20myArray%3A%20StringArray%3B%0D%0AmyArray%20%3D%20%5B%22Bob%22%2C%20%22Fred%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyArray.push('Barney')%3B%0D%0A):

```
interface StringArray {
   [index: number]: string;
}

var myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

myArray.push('Barney'); // <- push doesn't exist ??
```

Is that interface not a regular array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be just like a regular array, if you tell the compiler it is:

```
interface StringArray extends Array<string> {
   [index: number]: string;
}
```

By default, your `StringArray` only has the members you define. There are some cases where an array-like structure doesn't support all array methods, even though it has an indexer like an array - but in your case, extending the `Array` interface will solve your issue.

Full example:

```
interface StringArray extends Array<string> {
   [index: number]: string;
}

var myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

myArray.push('Barney'); // now ok
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't define an interface that is an array but define an array which has the interface as type:

```
var myArray: string[];
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
myArray.push('Barney');
```

I like this more because it is easier but to be honest, I don't know if there is a difference in functionallity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to bypass that issue. You just use the array length property and assign the new values to the end of the array.

```
interface StringArray {
   [index: number]: string;
}
var myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

myArray[myArray.length] = 'Barney';
```